# publish a live excel file with macros and sql server connection to a webpage

Tags: excel, web, vba

Does anyone know if it is possible to publish an Excel file with a live data that update themselves constantly to a Web page. I've seen that you can publish a normal excel file with an embed code from google drive, which uses iframe. But my excel file are using both macros and vba and google drive did not accept these. I've searched and looked for something similar to my case but did not find anything that works out.

Answer (score 2):

Excel files need to run on a local computer and are not made to present live data on the web. You need Excel installed on the computer you want to run the VBA code (macros). But the Excel file can be downloaded by a user and run locally.

Google Tables are running in the cloud on Google servers (and are therefore accessible through their web interface which you can implement into your webpage). What actually happens when you upload an Excel file to Google Drive it gets converted into a Google Table. Google Tables do not support VBA so only the Data is converted.

Google Tables != Excel Sheets (even if they look similar and support similar functionality, they are not the same)

Answer (score 0):

You will NOT get VBA to run in a web-baaed environment.  I mean, you can download HTML data from the web, and upload data to the web, using VBA, but it will not RUN in any kind of Internet environment.  Basically, VBA is designed to run on your desktop, or a server machine, only.  You probably want to learn HTML, or Java, or Python, or ASP.NET, if you really want to do what you described.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me some guideline if I'm going to try and do it from scratch.